# RegEx to match multiple optional groups of elements (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression to match the following kind of strings in Javascript:

- `/foo[123abc]/`
- `/foo[123abc]/bar[cba321]/`
- `/foo[52.1,23.3]/bar[52.2,23.42]/`
- `/foo[52.1,23.3]/bar[52.2,23.42]/baz[abc123]/`
- `/foo[52.1,23.3]/bar[52.2,23.42]/baz[12.1,42.23]/quux[2u33-c0ffee]/`

I want to split them up in name and the address inside square brackets. Additionally, they can be optional and the trailing slash is optional, too.

Just to illustrate that thing:

```
/foo[123abc]/
```

should deliver

```
"foo", "123abc"
```

And

```
/foo[123abc]/bar[52.1,23.42]
```

should deliver

```
"foo", "123abc"
"bar", "52.1,23.42"
```

But

```
/foo/bar
```

should not match.

Sorry that I didn't add my current proposals.

The best thing I currently have is:

```
/(?:\/([^\[]+)\[([^\]]+)\])?/
```

It matches the group but only a single one. If I add a global modifier it starts to eat the second result, which means

```
foo, 123abc
bar  cba321
```

becomes

```
foo[123abc]
bar cba321
```

.

Interestingly it works better in [regex101](http://regex101.com) than in my nodejs test script.

Answer (score 2):

This regular expression works for me:

```
\/(\w+)(?:\[([^\]]+)\])
```

See here: http://regex101.com/r/aC6tI6

Comment: Thanks, that works if the string is correct but doesn't match all criteria. I will update my question to show what I have for now.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with regex101.com thefourtheye!